# "Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled" by converting my project to swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I try to convert my project to Swift 2, and I encounter the following error

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Here's my code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     super.viewDidLoad()

     let query = PFUser.query()
     query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)

     var userArray = query!.findObjects() as! [PFUser]
     user = userArray[0]
    }
```

The errors are on the following lines:

```
 var userArray = query!.findObjects() as! [PFUser]
 user = userArray[0]
```

Can you help me please ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: What makes you think this is a duplicate apart from the identical title? :-)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get your code to compile and run is to add `try!` at the beginning of the offending line.

However, this is unsafe, as is your use of force unwrapping.

I recommend you read [Swift Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) on more info on how to deal with responding to and recovering from error conditions.

You should also read some material on Optionals. I suggest you start with the [language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)